# Error while declaring a list of lists in django

Tags: python, arrays, django

I am trying to declare an array in django, however I need one more column, since in my case the array position [0] [0] should be empty for better table display but when I will declare the array in my view

```
Matrice = [[0 for i in range (len (evaluators) +1)] for j in range (len (candidates))]
```

And I refresh the page I get the error:

> Need 2 values to unpack in for loop; Got 3.

The problem is in "len (evaluators) +1" because when I shoot +1 it works perfectly.

Why am I not able to declare the array this way? In the shell (python3 mana.py shell) this worked without problems ...

**views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404
from .models import Candidate, Criterion, Evaluation
from django import forms
from .forms import CandForm
from .forms import EvalForm
from .forms import TestForm
from django.shortcuts import redirect
from django.db import IntegrityError


def canditate_list(request):
    candidates = Candidate.objects.all()

    eva = Evaluation.objects.all()
    eval_cand_list = []                                     #aqui guarda uma lista com os FK candidates convertidos p/ str
    var = 0
    var2 = {'v1':2}
    context = {
        'candidates': candidates,
        'eva': eva,
        'var': var,
        'var2':var2
    }
    return render(request, 'app/candidate_list.html',context)

def candidate_detail(request, pk):
    candidate = get_object_or_404(Candidate, pk=pk)
    c_name = candidate.name                                 #pega o nome (string) do candidato
    c1 = Evaluation.objects.all()                           #guarda tds Evaluation na variavel  
    scores = []                                             #declara a array que vai receber as notas
    for c in c1:                                            
        cand = str(c.candidate)                             #guarda o nome do candidato do Evaluation atual
        if cand == c_name:                                  #confere se o Evaluation atual corresponde ao candidate atual(pk)
            scores += [c.score]

    soma = 0                                                #variavel que guardara a soma declarada
    for s in scores:
        soma += s                                           #faz a soma dos scores

    average = 0 
    if len(scores) > 0:
        average = soma/len(scores)                              #tira a média

    context = {
        'candidate': candidate,
        'average': average,
    }

    return render(request, 'app/candidate_detail.html', context)

"""
def evaluation(request):
    list_evaluation = Evaluation.objects.all()
    form2 = EvalForm()
    cont = 0

    if request.method == "POST":
        form2 = EvalForm(request.POST)
        if form2.is_valid():
            for ev in list_evaluation:
                cont += 1
"""
def evaluation(request):
    # form2 initialization
    list_evaluation = Evaluation.objects.all()
    form2 = EvalForm()
    marker = False

    if request.method == "POST":
        form2 = EvalForm(request.POST)
        if form2.is_valid() == True:
            for e in list_evaluation:
                if e.appraiser == form2.cleaned_data['appraiser'] and e.candidate == form2.cleaned_data['candidate']:
                    marker = True
                    break
            if marker == False:
                post = form2.save(commit=False)
                post.save()
                return redirect('canditate_list')
            else:
                form2 = EvalForm()
                error = 'Você já valiou esse candidato'
                return render(request, 'app/evaluation.html', {'criterions': form2,'error':error})
    else:
        form2 = EvalForm()
    return render(request, 'app/evaluation.html', {'criterions': form2,})

def register(request):
    list_evaluation = Evaluation.objects.all()

    if request.method == "POST":
        form = CandForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            post = form.save(commit=False)
            post.save()
            return redirect('candidate_detail', pk=post.pk)
    else:
        form = CandForm()
    return render(request, 'app/register.html', {'form': form})


def grid(request):
    evaluation = Evaluation.objects.all()           #queryset com tds os obj avaliação
    cont = 0
    evaluators = []                                 #lista que guarda os avaliadores sem repeti-los
    for evaluator in evaluation:
        cont = 0
        for e in evaluators:
            if e != evaluator.appraiser:
                cont += 1

        if cont == len(evaluators):
            evaluators += [evaluator.appraiser]


    cont = 0
    candidates = []                                 #lista que guarda os avaliador sem repeti-los
    for cand in evaluation:
        cont = 0
        for c in candidates:
            if c != cand.candidate:
                cont += 1

        if cont == len(candidates):
            candidates += [cand.candidate]

    colunas = len(evaluators)+1
    #                           Numero de colunas               Numero de linhas                    
    matrice = [[0 for i in range(len(evaluators)+1)] for j in range(len(candidates))]   




    cont = 0        
    context = {                                     #aqui eh o nome que as variaveis terao la no template
            'evaluators':evaluators,
            'evaluation':evaluation,
            'candidates':candidates, 
            'cont':cont,
            'matrice':matrice,
        }

    return render(request, 'app/grade.html', context)
```

**template**

```
</!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title></title>
  <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<body>

<p>{{ evaluators }}</p>
<p>{{ candidates }}</p>
<p>{{ matrice }}</p>

{% for m,n in matrice %}
<p>{{m}},{{n}}</p>
{%endfor%}
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do something like this

```
{% for nodes in matrices %}
  <p>
  {% for node in nodes %}
    {{node}},
  {% endfor %}
  </p>
{% endfor %}
```